# Using AuthenticationContext & ActiveDirectoryClient with an application proxy?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-ad-graph-api

Using the Azure Active Directory Graph Client API, how would I configure the underlying HttpClient to use an HttpClientHander, where I can define an authenticated application proxy?

```
var proxy = new WebProxy(...);
proxy.Credentials = ...;
var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Proxy = proxy, UseProxy = true};
var auth = new AuthenticationContext(...);
var client = new ActiveDirectoryClient(...);
```

Or, can I not use the Graph Client behind a proxy?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was exploring the same problem. It took some digging, but I found a solution. Now, I realize you asked specifically how to apply an `HttpClientHandler`. I don't know if this can be done; however, you can apply a proxy. Here's how.

The `ActiveDirectoryClient` class provides a `DataServiceContextWrapper` property called `Context`, which is, not surprisingly, a wrapper to a `DataServiceContext`.

This is good. It reduces the problem to figuring out how to apply a proxy to the `DataServiceContext` class. I used some old code I had sitting around, and things pretty much exploded. This is because I used the deprecated `SendingRequest` event to intercept a request and apply a proxy before it goes out the door. This client is not compatible with the deprecated event.

It took a little more digging to figure out how to do it with the `SendingRequest2` event; it only required a little type casting.

**Do this:**

```
var client = new ActiveDirectoryClient(...);
client.Context.SendingRequest2 += OnSendingRequest2;

// ...

static void OnSendingRequest2(object sender, SendingRequest2EventArgse)
{
    var request = ((HttpWebRequestMessage)e.RequestMessage).HttpWebRequest;
    request.Proxy = new WebProxy("http://myproxy:port");
}
```

**Don't Do This: (It is deprecated and will produce an exception.)**

```
var client = new ActiveDirectoryClient(...);
client.Context.SendingRequest += OnSendingRequest;

// ...

static void OnSendingRequest(object sender, SendingRequestEventArgs e)
{
    e.Request.Proxy = new WebProxy("http://myproxy:port");
}
```

Comment: Thanks kbrimington, I appreciate the effort. I'll mark it as an answer, but I won't be able to verify in a timely fashion.

Answer (score 0):

a bit late but i ran into the same issue.
using the code below in app.config saved my day !

```
 <system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
  </system.net>
```